# @philly25/react-native-paytm Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE reponse is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, paytm

I am getting undefined in console when I use this code from @philly25/react-native-paytm

plase help

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Paytm.addListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse());
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Paytm.removeListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse());
  }

  onPayTmResponse = (resp) => {
    console.log("hi " + resp);  // here getting undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be as follows:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    Paytm.addListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Paytm.removeListener(Paytm.Events.PAYTM_RESPONSE, this.onPayTmResponse);
  }

  onPayTmResponse = (resp) => {
    console.log("hi " + resp);  // here getting undefined
  }
```

Check out the official package docs for more information.

https://github.com/opsway/react-native-paytm#readme

Comment: yes. when I removed that bracket () then onPayTmResponse not even calling nothing printting over there. thats why add (). but now its getting undefined

Comment: I have updated the answer please have a look into the official docs for more information

Answer (score 0):

This is not Paytm official code please use the plugin on Paytm github link. For more information please visit Paytm Developer Portal